# Powershell add lines before specific string

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have to insert content before the specific string.

My current code is

```
$FileName = "C:\Users\ahmo500\Desktop\test\test.txt"
(Get-Content $fileName) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $_ # send the current line to output
        if ($_ -match "/indexes") 
        {
            #Add Lines before the selected pattern 
            "<index>"
            "<param>..<param>"
            "</index>"
        }
    } | Set-Content $fileName
```

The lines are added after `</indexes>` string but I want to add before `</indexes>`

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

test.txt sample content

```
              <configuration>
                  <indexes>
                     <index id="test_web_index">
                                <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrCloudSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                                <param desc="core">
                                    <patch:delete />
                                </param>
                                <param desc="rebuildcore">
                                    <patch:delete />
                                </param>                        
                      </index>
                      <index>
                       ..
                      </index>
                      <index>
                       .. 
                      </index>
                    </indexes>        
              </configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry what do you mean. Can you tell me which line needs to change?

Comment: Simply move the output of the current line `$_` behind the `if(..){code block}` . BTW better treat XML files as such with XML tools.

Comment: Do you mean i should use $file.insert?

Comment: No, he means loading the file into powershell as an actual `XmlDocument` type and manipulating that instead of going through the file line-by-line. Google "powershell xml insert nodes"

Comment: If i move the output from the if block then I won’t have anything inside the if block. Sorry i am still not getting exactly. Would you mind where exactly changes need to be made in my code? Thanks @lotpings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the output of the current line `$_` behind the if(..){code block} .

```
$FileName = "C:\Users\ahmo500\Desktop\test\test.txt"
(Get-Content $fileName) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match "/indexes") 
        {
            #Add Lines before the selected pattern 
            "<index>"
            "<param>..<param>"
            "</index>"
        }
        $_ # send the current line to output
    } | Set-Content $fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a XML-like solution would be preferable for the XML file?

```
$xreader = [System.Xml.XmlTextReader]::new('test.txt')
$xreader.Namespaces = $false
$xdoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xdoc.Load($xreader)
$index = $xdoc.CreateElement('index')
$index.InnerXml = '<param>..</param>'
[void]$xdoc.configuration.indexes.AppendChild($index)
$xdoc.Save('test_new.txt')
Get-Content test_new.txt
```

**Output:**

```
<configuration>
  <indexes>
    <index id="test_web_index">
      <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrCloudSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
      <param desc="core">
        <patch:delete />
      </param>
      <param desc="rebuildcore">
        <patch:delete />
      </param>
    </index>
    <index>
      ..
    </index>
    <index>
      .. 
    </index>
    <index>
      <param>..</param>
    </index>
  </indexes>
</configuration>
```